# Select a Org dynamically for private transaction in a channel

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am using Hyperledger Fabric 2.3. I have added 50+ Orgs in a channel. An Org1 wants to choose Org(i) **dynamically** to perform a transaction, but transaction details should be visible to only Org1 and Org(i) only.
What are the possible ways to achieve it?

Answer (score 2):

The solution to this kind of scenario is already available in fabric. You can use Private Data Collection(PDC) to keep the transaction data private between the two or more Orgs.

When you have PDC in place the data is shared only among the required Orgs and other Orgs that are not part of that transaction will just hold the transaction hash.

you can refer to [this](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.2/private-data/private-data.html) for more details on PDC's

Comment: Is it not necessary to mention the participating Orgs2 explicitly in the config file?

Comment: yes, you need to define them explicitly